# Java ArrayList Serialization issues

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, arraylist

I seem to recall an issue when you are trying to serialize ArrayLists in Java. I have run into the problem and cannot figure it out.

I send an ArrayList through a socket and then when I send it again, the ArrayList doesn't get transmitted correctly (even though the ArrayList has been modified) I recall this has something to do with not flushing the stream or something. Can anyone help me remember the issue and how to solve it?

Comment: Please post code so we can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by 'doesn't get transmitted correctly' you mean 'doesn't get updated at the peer' you need to call `ObjectOutputStream.reset()` before re-sendng an instance after it's been changed.